Why can I not update the default values of a derived class through a constructor?
I am trying to wrap my head around inheritance.
I've created a BasePerson class that has some protected elements, and those elements have default values. I'm trying to "update" those default values in a derived class with other values, and call them from outside the class in the main.cpp file.
If I've understood inheritance properly, I should be able call the derived class from the main file and have the "updated" elements displayed, but I've made an error somewhere as only the default values from the base class are shown.
I've gotten the code to the point where, if I want, I can update the values from the main.cpp file, but this isn't what I'm trying to do.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BasePerson.h"
using namespace std;

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BasePerson
{
protected :
    string st_firstName;
    string st_lastName;

public :
    double d_wagePerHour;

    BasePerson()
    {
        st_firstName = "Default First Name";
        st_lastName = "Default Last Name";
        d_wagePerHour = 40.12;
    }

    BasePerson(string param_firstName, string param_lastName, double param_wage)
    {
        st_firstName = param_firstName;
        st_lastName = param_lastName;
        d_wagePerHour = param_wage;
    }

    //Print-all Function
    void fn_printAllInfo()
    {
        cout << "First Name: " << st_firstName << "\n" << "Last Name: " << st_lastName << "\n" << "Wage Per Hour: " << d_wagePerHour << endl;
    }
};

class Employee : public BasePerson
{
private :
    string st_career;

public :
    Employee()
    {
       st_career = "Default Career";
    }

    Employee(string param_firstName, string param_lastName, double param_wage, string param_career) : BasePerson(param_firstName, param_lastName, param_wage)
    {
        st_firstName = "Bob";
        st_lastName = "Vila";
    }
};

/*
    Notes:

        - Anything private will be inaccessible from the derived class and outside
        - Anything protected will be accessible from the derived class and inaccessible from the outside
        - Public is public.
*/

int main()
{
    BasePerson person1;
    person1.fn_printAllInfo();

    Employee emp1;
    emp1.fn_printAllInfo();

    return 0;
}


I don't see anywhere in main where you are constructing Employee with anything other than the default constructor.

This question will probably be closed as too basic.  If you use the      constructor or Employee  that sets the overidden values, they will be overridden in the child class, but you are using the default constructor for Employee which just uses the base class values.

Employee emp1; -- Maybe let's ask you -- what do you expect this code to do?  If we can get an insight on why you believe this should call a constructor with those arguments, then maybe it can be explained as an answer.

Voting to close this as a typo.  You wrote two differerent constructors for Employee.  Which one do you think you are using?

@PaulMcKenzie -- You've helped me before, so I appreciate this (very new to c++). What   I thought would happen is despite the baseclass having default values, if the derived class reset those values, then if the default constructor of the derived class was called, the updated defaults would be shown.

You #include "BasePerson.h" and define the class BasePerson in the same file? What does BasePerson.h contain?

This might be noise at this point, but protected data is a bad idea because any issues with the data can be from any derived class. Better to make the data private and provide protected accessors and mutators. This allows the base class to set guard rails, and be the one place you look if you end up having state issues.

@TheodoreSteiner step through your code in a debugger.  You never run the code that "reset those values".  You are calling the Employee() constructor, and not the other constructor

"that has some protected elements" -- try one protected element. Once you have one working, you can worry about the others (if they are still a problem). Keep it simple for your question.

"I'm trying to 'update' those default values in a derived class with other values, and call them from outside the class in the main.cpp file." -- I am having trouble connecting this claim with your code. Part of the problem is that there is too much code. Eliminating the unused constructors would help reduce the noise (and maybe reveal that what you thought was unused is used). Maybe eliminate person1 as well. Another thing that would help is including your actual and expected output, since I might be able to link the expected output to the assignment you think is being executed.

First of all, I'd caution that I don't see many of what I consider good uses for inheritance.Although this does make some actual use of it, I think the case for it is still fairly weak.
Good uses for inheritance nearly always involve the base class declaring at least one virtual function, and the derived class providing an implementation of that virtual function. I've added a (semi-)useful virtual function to demonstrate at least the general idea.
Second, it seems to me that you're overloading constructors in a situation where it's probably simpler and more straightforward to just provide default parameter values instead.
Third, when a ctor is going to initialize a value, it's generally better for it to do so in an initializer list rather than doing an assignment in the body of the ctor. Sometimes (e.g., initializing a reference) this is strictly required; most other times it's still preferable. I'd say at least 90% of the time that I write a ctor at all, its body is empty.
Fourth, by default data should be private. If you think you have a good reason for protected data, write it down and think about it first. Then if you've thought it through, and you're 100% certain that the circumstances justify making it protected in this particular, highly unusual case, then you can go ahead and make it private.
Fifth, to print an object of some class, I'd provide an overload of operator<< to do that.
Sixth, formatting code for readability is quite important.
class BasePerson
{
private:
    string st_firstName;
    string st_lastName;
    double d_wagePerHour;
public:
    BasePerson(string param_firstName = "Default First Name", 
                      string param_lastName = "Default Last Name", 
                      double param_wage=40.12)
    : st_firstName(param_firstName),
      st_lastName(param_lastName),
      d_wagePerHour(param_wage)
    {
    }

    virtual std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os) const { 
        return os << "First Name: " << st_firstName << "\n" 
                  << "Last Name: " << st_lastName << "\n" 
                  << "Wage Per Hour: " << d_wagePerHour << "\n";
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, BasePerson const &b) { 
        return b.print(os);
    }
};

class Employee : public BasePerson {
    string st_career;
public:
    Employee(string const &firstName = "Bob",
             string const &lastName = "Villa",
             double wage = 40.12,
             string career = "Default Career")
       : BasePerson(firstName, lastName, wage),
         st_career(career)
    {}

    virtual std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os) const override { 
        BasePerson::print(os);
        return os << "Career: " << st_career;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BasePerson person1;
    std::cout << person1 << "\n";

    Employee emp1;
    std::cout << emp1 << "\n";

    return 0;
}

Live on Godbolt

Thank you for your detailed explanation. As you can tell, I'm new to C++ and trying to put it altogether. Working of online tutorials and books so sometimes the "why" behind a certain implementation of code is based off a lesson. But I really appreciate the time you took to explain your answer

@TheodoreSteiner: yeah, that is somewhat difficult. Many online tutorials are (at least sort of) all right at teaching about specific features, but most I've seen are pretty poor at dealing with the big picture. C++ also has a lot of features that you sort of need to know about to know C++ well, but aren't used very often in real life.

Is there any book or source you recommend, to augment the learning? Maybe one that has stuck with you in your time?

The C++ Book List is worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/179910. My personal experience probably isn't all that helpful--I'd programmed in FORTRAN, BASIC, Pascal, C, etc., before C++ came along.

Well thank you for your help nonetheless, I really appreciate it

You aren't currently setting the values in the Employee default constructor. If you want the default constructor to set all three values try this:
Employee()
{
    st_career = "Default Career";
    st_firstName = "Bob";
    st_lastName = "Vila";
    
}

Employee(string param_firstName, string param_lastName, double param_wage, string param_career) 
: BasePerson(param_firstName, param_lastName, param_wage)
{
    st_career = param_career;
}

You should also look into initializing all of the member variables in the member initializer list:
Employee() : BasePerson("Bob", "Vila", 40.12), st_career("Default Career") {}

